# Interpreting the Chi Square for a 2x2 contingency table

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, independence

Here is my problem. I need to implement an algorithm to find if there is a dependency between 2 categorical variables. My population can vary a lot as it is an input I don't have control over. My chisquare function requires a population of 100 to work (which I set arbitrarily). I tried the chisquare with the example below which results in an extremely statistically significant dependency if my understanding is right?

This led me to believe that I don't understand what the Chi square is for. Intuitively, when I look at the dataset below, out of 100K males roughly 30% of them dislike tea and out of 134K women, 25% of them dislike tea... To me we're very far away to be able to establish a dependency, let alone an "extremely statistically significant" one.

If someone can explain what I am doing/getting wrong here?

[image: chi square test]

PS: The image was taken from : https://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/contingency1/

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong with the test per se. Chi squared tests for stochastic independence. I believe you may have misunderstood what the p value and significance actually tell you about your data.

Consider what the example you gave shows: If you know that someone is female, you would judge the chance of her liking tea to be higher than if the person is male. The proportional difference may not look like much, but the total sample in the table is very large. Because of this, the result turned out to be quite significant. This means that the chance of drawing this sample from a population in which preference for tea and gender are not associated is quite small.

You always have to judge for yourself if the association is actually meaningful. To put a number not to the significance but to the strength of the association, you can try calculating the Phi coefficient, which is similar to the correlation coefficient. It becomes 1 or -1 if the association is so strong that there is complete dependence, meaning that there are neither any male tea-likers nor any female tea-dislikers. It becomes 0 if the proportions of tea preference are the same in both groups.